# How to get a diameter of circle from based on its flattened width

Tags: geometry

I have a problem here where-in heat shrink tube that im going to buy are sold classified by its flattened width, now this makes it hard for me to determine if the one im going to choose will fit on where i will place them as wires cannot just be simply flattened and i can ruler them up.

How would i extrapolate the radius/diameter of tube if for example the tube is advertised to have a flattend width of 6mm. What formula would i use ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved using only basic circle geometry formulas.

The flattened width of the tube is half the circumference of the tube, and we can relate the circumference of the circle to the diameter. If $w$ is the flattened width and $d$ is the diameter,

we have $2w=\pi d$, so $d=\frac{2w}{\pi}$

In your example, the diameter of a 6 mm wide flattened tube is approximately $3.82$ mm